# Creating an additive structure over the set of all finite groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to form a ring (or ring-like structure) out of the set of all finite groups.

Has anyone created/encountered an operation "+" before with the follow properties.

Let $G_1, G_2$ be finite groups and |G| denote the size of G, then

$$ |G_1| + |G_2| = |G_1 + G_2|$$

Where the left hand side is addition amongst natural numbers and the right hand side is our "abstract group addition"

And let $\times$ denote the direct product. Then:

$$ G_1 \times ( G_2 + G_3) = (G_1 \times G_2) + (G_1 \times G_3) $$

The "+" ideally would be commutative and associative, but I'm not sure if such an operator can necessarily exist.

My goal is to try to denote a notion of "rational groups" and dedekind cuts to groups to see if I can create a "fractional group theory" so to speak.

Comment: That would fail the distributive multiplicative identity. Since the RHS would be cyclic, but the LHS would a direct product of some group and a cyclic group

Comment: Let $e$ denote the trivial group, then $e+e = C_2$ (cyclic group) and so for any $G,$ $G\times C_2 = G\times (e+e) = G + G$.

Comment: BTW, great story about linear optimization and drug dealers!

Comment: Technicality: "All finite groups" is a class, not a set. "All isomorphism classes of finite groups" is a set.

Comment: There are $14$ ways to choose $H$ of order $16$ and $15$ ways to pick $K$ of order $81.$ All $210$ combinations must lead to $H+K$ being cyclic of order $97.$ So that operation does not respect the internal group structure much. All that seems possible is to have $H+K$ always be the cyclic group of order  $|H|+|K|.$ But then one is forced to interpret $H\times  K$ as not the direct product but rather the cyclic group of order $|H||K|.$

Comment: Every homomorphism from this additive magma to an abelian group would factor through $\mathbf{Z}$. Indeed, denoting by $c_n$ the image of the cyclic group of order $n$, we would have $pc_1=c_p$ for all prime $p$. Then I claim that for every $n\ge 1$, if $g$ is the image of a group of order $n$, then $g=nc_1$. Proof by induction on $n$; it's clear for $n=1$. For given $n\ge 2$, there is a prime $p$ with $n\le p<2n$; the case $n$ prime being ok, we can suppose $p>n$. Then $g+c_{p-n}=c_p$, so $g+(p-n)c_1=pc_1$, thus $g=nc_1$. So the group associated with such a structure would be quite poor.

Comment: A related notion is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_category. Note it mentions Groups do not form such a category, but without explanation. It looks like your structure would be akin to a distributive category structure on Groups that is compatible with the distributive structure on (finite) Sets via the forgetful functor.

Comment: @Asvin thats a good point! Perhaps a collection of identities can be assembled for the operator. Also thank you! :) glad to see the blog is spreading, twas a strange encounter that one summer eve.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that we can get a commutative, associative operation as follows. Let $G=A\times B$ and $H=A\times C$, where $B$ and $C$ have no common factor (when written as a direct product of indecomposable groups of order greater than one). Define $G+H=A\times D$, where $D$ is a product of cyclic groups of prime order such that $|D|=|B|+|C|$.